# Special Characters interpreted but not part of the actual file name - resulting in exception

Tags: java, exception, jvm, filenotfoundexception

I am currently creating a File in a folder location and another process reads the contents of this file, however even though the file is created without any special character, I am now getting a FileNotFoundException thrown due to these two special characters ~$, BUT these special characters is not part of the physical file name *"verifysinglenumber_20210208203905995.xls"* which means they do not exist as part of the file and not even prefixed with these characters

*When the file is created Note those special characters*

New File just created D:\Java\IdeaProjects - Single Number - BAU\Selenium\src\test\resources\path files\ : ~$verifysinglenumber_20210208203905995.xls

*This is the Exception and please note those special characters ~$*

java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Java\IdeaProjects - Single Number - BAU\Selenium\src\test\resources\path files~$verifysinglenumber_20210208203905995.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)

*The Strings sPolling Path and Resource Paths is just building the string for the location*

```
public XSSFSheet GetExcelSheet(String workbookName, String sheetName, String sPollingPath) throws Exception {
    excelFile = new File(resourceFolderPath + sPollingPath + workbookName);
    try
    {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

I am also using the JNotifier, to listen in on the folder when the new excel file is created.

Can you guys please help and explain to me why the File is interpreted with these special characters even though they are not even there?

[image]

Comment: Just made a few changes to the post, there were a few mistakes in the text

Comment: What makes you think that those characters are not there?  `File` does not add characters to the pathname spontaneously. Those characters most likely come from `resourceFolderPath` or `sPollingPath` or  `workbookName`.  Try adding some print statements or something to see what the variables actually contain ... immediately before you concatenate them.

Comment: @Stephen C, Thanks for the reply, I am already printing them out and the characters are displayed, however I am running the exact same process on my local machine and I do not see the issue, the file is printed without those special characters when running locally.

Comment: So you need to find out where the (incorrect) values >>in the variables<< are coming from.  Or provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can figure it our for you.  Until you find out where those characters are actually coming from, you won't be able to solve this.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to remove all (String sanitized = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]", ""); unwanted characters from the string before the Listener detects the file, I am however still not sure where those unwanted characters are coming from, it seems the JNotify Listener creates these characters each time the file is generated but the physical characters are never prefixed to the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use the Watch Service API as advised and updating this answer with this resolution.

```
 public static void watchFolderPickup() throws Exception {
WatchService watchyFier = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

Path pickupLocation = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\localUser\\Documents\\IdeaProjects - Single Number - BAU\\Selenium\\src\\test\\resources\\path files\\");
WatchKey directoryWatchKey = pickupLocation.register(watchyFier, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);



while (true)
    for(WatchEvent<?> event : directoryWatchKey.pollEvents()){
        WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
        Path fileName = ev.context();
        String fileInLocation = fileName.getFileName().toString();

        BAUFileNameSetter setFilename =  new BAUFileNameSetter();
        setFilename.setFileName(fileInLocation);
        dataSetfilename = setFilename.getFileName();
        System.out.println("File Created for New Request");
        BaseTest.setup();
        return;
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Does JNotify offer any additional feature over Java’s builtin file notification facility, besides inserting those characters you have to remove?

Comment: @Holger, Hi, I am not sure because I am fairly new to JNotify, but it seems it could be a setting in Windows Server that causes this to occur, when running this locally on Windows 10 I don't have this issue. But it seems I am not the first to see this issue here is another post : https://superuser.com/questions/901730/why-do-i-see-filename-hidden-excel-files

Comment: But why are you using JNotify at all? I understand why JNotify had been created, two decades ago when Java didn’t have a notification API. But in 2021, a developer should first give the built-in notification feature a try, before resorting to an ancient 3rd party library. Since you can’t say why you are using it, it seems you didn’t try the built-in API. Besides that, the link is telling an entirely different story. The files *have* that name, but they are temporary, so when you try to open them, they are either, still locked (in use) or already deleted.

Comment: Thanks, i will give the built-in Notification API a read and I will try it out

Comment: @Holger, thanks for pointing me to this API.

Comment: Thank you, the WatchService API works perfect and took a few minutes to implement.